# How to turn on PHP auto-complete in Adobe-Brackets

Tags: php, autocomplete, code-completion, adobe-brackets

I have installed [Adobe-Brackets 0.41](http://brackets.io/?lang=en). And I installed following extensions :

- [Integrated Development](https://github.com/jadbox/brackets-integrated-development)
- PHP Syntax Hint
- [QuickDocsPHP](https://github.com/Wikunia/brackets-QuickDocsPHP)

But when I writing PHP code (for instance `mysql_`) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> it won't complete the PHP codes!

Does brackets support PHP auto-complete at all?

Any ideas?

**P.S:**

Auto-Complete works fine with `HTML` and `CSS` codes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a hint extension for brackets now!

https://github.com/mackenza/Brackets-PHP-SmartHints

Btw I hope you like my QuickDocsPHP extension ;)

Comment: I know I like your extension :D

Comment: Holy!! You are the creator. Cooooooool